# Sites that Use Metropolitan Statistical Areas (MSAs)

Tags: search

I'm looking for examples of sites that use the metropolitan statistical areas (MSAs) to filter results.

In this scenario, a user can select Tri-State area from a drop down and return the results for a given region instead of typing in New York, NY and getting more specific results.

The advantage is that there are only 280 MSAs, making it easier to return results for smaller data sets.

Anyway, if anyone can point me towards a site that uses this search filter, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I'm actually upvoting this question because I can see why help was needed to find a site that used this information as part of the filter options - really not easy to find niche examples like this.

Comment: I think the consensus was just towards closing the question as it seemed unanswerable.

Comment: I upvoted this because I actually have several applications that work with MSA's. I haven't implemented it in any great way and was looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit more complicated than for your needs, but there is [the US census factfinder for 2010/11](http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml)

To get the second view below you have to select *Geographies* on the left, and in the *Select Geographies* popup filter-helper dialog, choose *Metro/Micro* area under the first set of filter options, after which the filter options changes to the list shown in the first image below. you can then narrow down on the MSA and select one or more which adds it to your top level geography filters - within which you can examine the census data.

I found this filter system incredibly complicated to use and it seemed sometimes I had to refresh back to the link above and start again in order to find the same options available.

But it's the only example of a site I could find that uses the MSA as part of the search filter.

[image]

[image]